# mysql duplicates search based on different column values

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I am having two tables. 1st table have id, First name, last name and phone number columns. 2nd table have state, district, block, and village columns.
id column have unique values. Other columns can have duplicate values.

I want to select all records having same first name, last name, state, district, block and village values but different phone number values.

for example:

```
ID  First Name  Phone Number    District    State   Block   Village
1   Rajesh      9876543210       ABC        XYZ     GHI     PQR
2   Jim         7894561230       WXY        DEF     JKL     SDF
3   Jack        8745963210       EWQ        REW     YTR     POI
4   Rajesh      9856741230       ABC        XYZ     GHI     PQR
5   Jack        8745963210       EWQ        REW     YTR     POI
```

The out put should include 1st and 4th records and **not** 3rd and 5th as they are having same phone number.

I have selected all duplicate rows with same phone number by using the following query:

```
SELECT b.phone_mobile, g.countID, b.id
FROM (
SELECT phone_mobile, COUNT( id ) AS countID
FROM contacts
GROUP BY phone_mobile                
HAVING COUNT( id ) >1
)g
INNER JOIN contacts b ON b.phone_mobile = g.phone_mobile
```

Now I am not getting how to select all rows with same name and location but different phone number. I need help.

Thank you.

Comment: first you show your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select all rows if there is a row with the same name,address but another ID and Phone_number:

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts c
JOIN address a on c.id=a.id
WHERE EXISTS
 (
  SELECT 1
    FROM contacts c1
    JOIN address a1 on c1.id=a1.id
    WHERE c1.ID<>c.id
          AND c1.Phone_Number<>c.Phone_Number
          AND c1.First_Name=c.First_Name
          AND a1.District=a.District
          AND a1.State=a.State
          AND a1.Block=a.Block
          AND a1.Village=a.Village
  )
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b961/3)</kbd>

Comment: I tried to run this query on my database table having 79665 records through phpmyadmin, but the query is loading forever. Any idea for this ever loading problem?

Comment: Try to add indexes on id,First_Name,District,State,Block,Village

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for you. At times its good to have a correct database schema.

What I mean by correct is. If you use normalization here while making database. You will have to deal with much simpler query.

After observing your tables. I would recommend having Phone column in a different table. So you could have like. Each user can have many phone numbers, doing so will solve the problem of querying.

So now when you have taken phone column out of the table. Automatically you will have distinct user rows with multiple phone number. And whenever you pull a user just have a where clause to connect to the phone number table and there you go. You have user with multiple unique phone numbers.

```
Select * from users U,phone P where U.id = P.user_id
```

Or

```
Select * from users U, phone P where U.id = P.user_id and U.firstname = 'john'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Distinct will give distinct values for all columns.

Comment: Sorry, but the table structure can't be changed.

Comment: Why is that ? I guess the idea is to be doing right then simply getting an answer. Have a look at this http://www.w3schools.in/dbms/database-normalization/ and if you change your mind. In future if you are working with much huge database. You will need normalization technique